# Alternatives for Bench Press

Tags: weightlifting, health, bench-press

My ophthalmologist advised me to avoid the bench press due to some **strain in the eyes.** 
But given the importance of bench press in body building and power lifting, avoiding bench press may have significant costs on the entire training regime.

Can anyone suggest any alternatives for the bench press, which have same/almost same effect on chest development?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your ophthalmologist doesn't know what they're talking about; fire them and hire someone better.

Comment: Dumbbell bench press?

Answer (score 2):

Push ups with plates on your back, with a backpack or between steps/parallels using a dipping belt.

Literally the same motion but the scapula are free to move so it uses more muscles allowing you to press more weight and more safely.

Weighted dips work too, get a 70kg (154lbs) weighted dip and I can assure you that your pecs and traps will blow up.